# Exact types of trpc.useQuery first argument for a wrapper hook

Tags: typescript, react-query, trpc.io

I'm trying to make a wrapper around *every* call to `trpc.useQuery`. It should look something like this:

```js
function wrapper(pathAndInput) {
  const result = trpc.useQuery(pathAndInput)
  /* some code that also uses `pathAndInput` */
  return result
}
```

However I can't make work the fact that the `pathAndInput` can have a variadic second element. I.e. in `trpc.useQuery(["key", params], options)` the `params` part is optional.

The type I have so far is this:

```js
function useIndexedTRcpQuery<TRouteKey extends TQuery>(
    pathAndInput: inferQueryInput<TRouteKey> extends (undefined | void | null)
        ? [TRouteKey]
        : [TRouteKey, inferQueryInput<TRouteKey>]
): UseQueryResult<inferQueryOutput<TRouteKey>>
```

However I get the following typescript error:

> ```
> trpc.useQuery(pathAndInput)
>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2
> ```

I have also tried the following:

```js
function useIndexedTRcpQuery<TRouteKey extends TQuery>(
    pathAndInput: [
        key: TRouteKey,
        args?: inferQueryInput<TRouteKey>,
    ],
): UseQueryResult<inferQueryOutput<TRouteKey>>
```

Which gives the following error :

> ```
> trpc.useQuery(pathAndInput)
>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> Source provides no match for variadic element at position 1 in target
> ```

### What is the correct way to type the first argument of `trpc.useQuery` as a generic?

---

For reference, here are what the "utils types" are in the above code (pretty standard trpc stuff):

```js
import type { UseQueryResult } from "react-query";
import type { inferProcedureOutput, inferProcedureInput } from "@trpc/server";

type TQuery = keyof AppRouter["_def"]["queries"];

type inferQueryInput<
  TRouteKey extends TQuery,
> = inferProcedureInput<AppRouter["_def"]["queries"][TRouteKey]>;

type inferQueryOutput<
  TRouteKey extends TQuery,
> = inferProcedureOutput<AppRouter["_def"]["queries"][TRouteKey]>;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you may define a type in the `trpc.ts` file. (or wherever you defined the other "pretty standard trpc stuff".

```ts
export type TUseQuery = [
  TQuery, // we use the already existing TQuery type which holds all possible querys
  Record<string, any> // We use a Record to type the Object consisting of keys in the form of strings and any possible input.
];
```

After that we can use the Type to type a query Parameter.

```ts
import { trpc, TUseQuery } from "../utils/trpc"; // path to your trpc file

let query: TUseQuery= [
    "example.hello", // trpcQuery
    { text: "from tRPC" }, // trpcQuery Input Object
] 

function laodData(query: TUseQuery) : UseQueryResult {
  return trpc.useQuery(query) 
}

console.log(laodData(query));
```

et voila.

PS: testet in the t3-demo-app.

Comment: Do you have an idea how this could look in tRPC v10?